# Imagecache actions textaction PHP code

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

In both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 I have a content type called image with an imagefield (field_img_field) and a text field called copyright (field_img_copyright).

In Drupal 6 I use Imagecache textactions to check the contents of field_img_copyright and, if there is text there, add that text to the image - a copyright watermark. The following PHP code does that.

```
if (!empty($node->field_img_copyright[0]['value'])) {
    return '© '.$node->field_img_copyright[0]['value'];
}
```

This code does not work in Drupal 7 though.

I have tried the methods in posts 1, 12 and 13 here:
https://drupal.org/node/1402790

but get errors along the lines of:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 1 of /home/.../modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Could somebody help plz, I'm pretty baffled.
Thanks.

Comment: I have used the code example in the readme.txt file in the imagcache_actions/image_effects_text folder and it works. BUT it throws up "EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7721 of /home/.../public_html/drupal/includes/common.inc)" error and won't let me edit the preset (unless I use the browser's back button). Very odd and annoying

Comment: Seems the following code is crucial:
`if (!$image_context['entity']) {
  return 'No referring entity';
}`
I assumed I didn't need it as the images i am manipulating are always referred from an entity. Ho hum!

Comment: Did this answer your question? Then simply post the working code as an answer and mark your own answer as correct – that should do the trick for others searching for the solution.